# Passing url from excel to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, cookies

i came across with annoying issue, which i can solve. I have URL in Excel linking to my aspx page:

```
http://localhost/Myapp/Web/ServiceTicket/ServiceTicketReportView.aspx?ServiceTicketID=21336&CustomerID=7118
```

in the browser its shown like this:

```
http://localhost/Myapp/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMyapp%2fWeb%2fServiceTicket%2fServiceTicketReportView.aspx%3fServiceTicketID%3d21336%26CustomerID%3d7118&ServiceTicketID=21336&CustomerID=7118
```

that means that my application redirects to login page, which is fine. after the login im redirected to the page i want. But here is the issue, if im trying to open the same link again, im redirected to the login page and my link is not shown in url. To get rid of this i have to remove cookies.

BUT

if i pasting it directly to the address bar, coming from notepad, outlook or anywhere else, im asked to login just once and the url keeps my link.
Somehow it seems that it gets different cookies.

Any ideas?

**EDITED:**

I found this relevant topic, but no suitable solution...

https://superuser.com/questions/444984/excel-hyperlink-not-redirecting-properly-bug

**SOLVED:**

Looking around, i found this article which solved my problem. Its a work arround, as Excel messes up aspx sessions.
http://www.vc2go.com/2009/11/cookie-based-authentication-does-not-work-with-excel.html

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Redirect Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Please wait, redirecting...
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
function getQuerystring(key)
{
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  return qs[1];
}
window.location = "../" + getQuerystring('page');
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

cheers.

Comment: its probably because you use the localhost as the site name - consider to use IIS for make your tests, and make a local name, also correct setup web.config for that local web name.

Comment: But as I said, its fine if i go from notepad, outlook, gmail. But if its from excel its messed up..